# adding new sensor

Tags: grass-gis

i want to add new sensor in grass.
i followed the link http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/browser/grass/trunk/imagery/i.atcorr/README
 and created the .csv for our sensor.but where should i incorporate this in code. i checked iwave.cpp but iam not getting any clue.reading sensor type and no.of bands all should be mentioned to add a new sensor. may i know where can i find the information?

Comment: You might be better off asking this on a GRASS developers mailing list. Full details of all the mailing lists are at http://grass.osgeo.org/support/mailing-lists/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a helper script as well in the code:

http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/browser/grass/trunk/imagery/i.atcorr/create_iwave.py

It generates the filter function IWave.cpp template from the csv file.

Comment: If the sensor if of wider interest, we may also include it in the official code.

Comment: for Aerial data if we have RSR ,  can we use create_iwave.py for interpolation?

Comment: i am having aerial data and corresponding RSR.If i interpolate using create_iwave.py, error is shown ValueError: A value in x_new is below the interpolation range. wavelengths starts at 454nm and ends at 860nm.b1 with 70,b2 70,b3 60,b4 90 nanometers widths they have.can anyone suggest me how to interpolate.

Comment: While I think that i.atcorr only works for satellite data, the create_iwave.py has an issue. I have opened a ticket for this: https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ticket/3027

Comment: But I interpolated for Aerial data

Comment: I opened a ticket for the script error: https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ticket/3027